# Cannot define T in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Any clue how to define T in this code?

```
 public static T ToEnum<T>(this string value, T defaultValue)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                return defaultValue;
            }

            T result;
            return Enum.TryParse<T>(value, true, out result) ? result : defaultValue;
        }
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS0453  The type 'T'
>   must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter
>   'TEnum' in the generic type or method 'Enum.TryParse(string,
>   bool, out TEnum)'

Comment: @PetSerAl Please write out the whole code like an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Please read [ask]. If you can define "this", you can search for it. Do you want a "generic type constraint for an enum"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a `constraint` to have a value type which is a `struct`, for sample:

```
public static T ToEnum<T>(this string value, T defaultValue)
      where T : struct 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    T result;
    return Enum.TryParse<T>(value, true, out result) ? result : defaultValue;
}
```

I haven't tested it.

Comment: Beat me by a second!

Comment: It gives the error `Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0451 The 'new()' constraint cannot be used with the 'struct' constraint  `

Comment: Try using the ´Enum` as a constraint!

Comment: Just remove `, new()` OP, an enum cannot be "new"

Comment: `where T : Enum` is not a valid template constraint in C#.